# PyCharm crashes when I start typing

Tags: python, crash, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community Edition and tried versions 2019.1.3 and 2019.1.2. I can create a new project and files to that project but as soon as I write anything (e.g: in a .py file, in a .html file or even entering the script path when adding a configuration) it crashes (also crashes when trying to edit an already existing project). Any suggestions what I can do to fix that?

Comment: How much ram do you have? And what os are you running?

Comment: RAM 16 GB and Mac OS 10.15 Beta but it has worked before

Comment: Hmm. Pycharm crashes with to little ram. That's  not your problem though..

Comment: I just found an error log named java_error_in_pycharm, first line says: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Comment: Hmm. Try reinstalling?

Comment: I already did, even tried different versions

Comment: Hmm. Try reinstalling in a different directory? You'll lose settings, but that will eliminate whether or not it's user caused.

Comment: how can I do that? where do I select where to install it?

Comment: In the install wizard there is an option for the directory to install it in. Select a different one from the default.

Comment: Has this helped?

Comment: Could you please try the latest PyCharm? It's available here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/. Just to check if the issue was fixed in bundled Java or not.

Comment: I get this error as well, in the crash report the event thread is crashing when PyCharm tries to call CGDataProviderCreateWithData with 0x0. Just as an experiment I tried turning off text aliasing and it didn't help. Also trashing preferences didn't help. It's odd because it was working for a few days.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Preferences/Appearance and select a different font, I used "Monospace" and things seem to work again.

On my system, PyCharm was crashing when it called into CoreText rendering.  Reinstalling and trashing preferences otherwise didn't work.